# Android: How can I open URL in Smart TV like Samsung or Android TV over WIFI?

Tags: java, android, android-tv, samsung-smart-tv

How can I open URL in Smart TV over WiFi? 
Example: I have in my application this button:

[image: Button]

And when I click on this button, It should show to me the list of TV's on WiFi and when I select some device, it should open web browser in Smart TV with the same URL.

How can I create something like this? 
Thank you for answer.

Comment: Have you tried anything? any research?

Comment: I wrote Air-Share to do exactly this. Not a small task.

Comment: what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the logo for 'Google Cast' what was called 'Chromecast' which is Google's sharing feature between devices like PC/mobile phone/tablet/Google Home appliance to TV/audio device with appropriate hardware.

See for more details: https://developers.google.com/cast/

Comment: Thank you! I looked for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Tizen has it's own native library Smart View SDK for this purpose.

More information with examples you can find here - http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/smart-view-sdk/introduction/